# Is there a way to retrieve information about a previously calculated route without a routeHandle in HERE Maps Routing API v8?

Tags: here-api

I have downloaded a bunch of routes from HERE Maps Routing API v8. At the time, I wasn't aware about the routeHandler parameter, so I didn't return it from my requests.

Now I need to acquire duration times with different departure times from these previously downloaded routes. Is there a way I can retrieve/calculate the routeHandler with all other information I have about the route? Or to retrieve the duration times for the routes without a routeHandler? (maybe with the route's id or polyline)

I thought of recalculating the routes, giving the same origin/destination, but I'm afraid the results may differ from my previous routes, since the API may return different routes based on departure time.

I found out that the Routing API v7 has a way to retrieve the route with routeID, but it doesn't work with the id returned by v8.

EDIT: I thought of making a request with the time the original routes were donwloaded as the departure time, in order to get the routeHandler, but I'm not sure the routes returned will be the same as the ones I have, because the departure time was set to 'now', and I don't know if requesting past times returns the same thing as before.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't specify parameter return=routeHandle in the request then you can't get previously calculated route (or routeHandle) neither by polyline nor route's id(doesn't exist in v8) nor by something else.

You are right, if you recalculate a route then you get different route response because it will be another traffic situation on the roads at departure time.

Caution: when you will decode route by routeHandle (/routes/{routeHandle}) and with different departure times then it will be used anyway always previously encoded route polyline(but of course with another penalties) therefore for some waypoints (`origin`, `destination`, `via`) combinations recalculated route could return more effizient route at particular departure time.